# Knockout: pass a value from controller to view and then pass it from view to viewmodel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm new to Knockout. Basically I need to get an array of items (pairs of price and quantity) from controller and then display it on my view. But before i display it, I want to use knockout to do some computation (calculate the subtotal) in the viewmodel, then pass the new array to the view. I know I can bind the original array to my view. But how can i pass this array to my viewmodel?

Comment: Please share code it is very hard to visualize where your are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You would not pass from a view to a viewmodel, it's the other way around. Controller passes data to a viewmodel, which is bound to a view. I digress.

There are several different techniques but a common one is to map the data into observable values. Knockout has a helper method `arrayMap` which will help convert items in the array into observables. An example below:

```js
var Item = function(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
  self.Price = ko.observable(data.Price);
  self.Qty = ko.observable(data.Qty);
  self.Total = ko.pureComputed(function() { return self.Price() * self.Qty();});
  }

var viewModel = function() {
  
  var self =this;
  
  // list of items
  self.Data = ko.observableArray([]);
  
  // simulate ajax call to fetch data
  self.Load = function() {
    var data = [
      { Name: "A", Price: 12.34, Qty: 1},
      { Name: "B", Price: 23.45, Qty: 2 },
      { Name: "C", Price: 1234.56, Qty: 3 }
    ];
    
    var mappedData = ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function(item) {
      return new Item(item);
    });
    
    this.Data(mappedData);
    }
  
  
  }

var vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: Data">
  <li>
Name: <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
    Quantity: <input type="text" data-bind="value: Qty" style="width: 100px;" />
    Price: <input type="text" data-bind="value: Price" style="width: 100px;" />
    Total: <span data-bind="text: Total"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
<p>Click the button to simulate a load from API
<button data-bind="click: Load">Load</button></p>
```

Comment: Sorry just realised I forgot to add a subtotal to this model, but it should be fairly easy to do. Add a computed value to `viewModel` and use the `ko.utils.arrayForEach` command to add up each row.